# How to compare two web objects?

Tags: compare

How to compare two web objects, objects may be web sites, profiles, web documents, etc.?
pseudo code function:

```
function compareWebObjcets(url1,url2){
float distance=1.0;
...
return distance; // value from 0.0 - objects are similar, 1.0 - max different.
}
```

Comment: @SMA this is a general question. it is not about a sepcific implementation obviously. it even says: "pseudo code function"!

Comment: Interesting, though I can't see many real life applications... Anyway, I'd say you need a set of criteria that _can_ be compared at all. First obviously you could consider header, so meta information like mimetype, size, encoding etc. Then maybe some empiric data about guessed language (if it is a text or code based mimetype), or maybe content list structure in case of archives... In the end combine all separate criteria and compute a sum.

Comment: On what criteria are you judging similarities? As it stands, this question is very broad.